# kubernetes flexvolume plugin for cifs

Tags: kubernetes, cifs

2.4 / coreos
I've instructed the kubelet to read plugins from a writable dir ( in coreos the default destination is read-only ):

```
--volume-plugin-dir=/etc/kubelet-plugins/volumeplugins
```

I've placed this handmade flexplugin

https://gist.github.com/fvigotti/65dc24b7f93074f1c59f81d0e3f31d04 
 (also 
contain pod for usage sample )

here:

```
/etc/kubelet-plugins/volumeplugins/fv~cifs/cifs
```

reloaded the kubelet ( done various tests, also restarted the node multiple times ) 
during kubelet bootstrap no message gets logged about loaded/errors-on volume plugins ( it is normal? )

anyway, when i create a pod that use the plugin I get this message logged :

```
volumes.go:132] Could not create volume builder for pod 98377409-3e1a-11e6-bb39-fa163e111b06: can't use volume plugins for test: no volume plugin matched
```

I don't know if the plugin is missing or the logged message isn't enought descriptive for the problem, also the documentation for the plugin is scarce, 
I suppose was an easy integration but at this point I don't know where to look to debug..

Thank you,
Francesco

Comment: Please post all the relevant code/configuration here. That said: No errors: Yes, that seems to be normal: It just loads the configs in the required context and only checks the context, so it does not check the use. Regarding the volume builder pod: What is the namespace configuration of the plugin and of the pod?

Comment: FYI I've derived a complete cifs plugin for CoreOS/Kubernetes based on your code: https://github.com/sigma/cifs_k8s_plugin (confirmed working with k8s 1.4.1 and CoreOS 1122.2.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can help someone ,
(there was serious bug in my first attempt, the biggest blocking probably was wrong args parsing for the `mount` command.. )

I've made a version of the plugin that works on kubernetes cluster 1.6.x

https://github.com/fvigotti/cifs_k8s_plugin

have a nice day,
Francesco